# Best way to convert a video while uploading - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, video-streaming, html5-video

It´s simple. I have a page where the user can upload a video that will be stored in a directory inside the application.

But, as we know, the user can upload a 2mb video or 700mb video. What I need to do is convert the video while uploading or after upload (I don´t know which is the best way), in order to avoid large videos stored on the server.

I´m not sure but I think Youtube do the same thing.

OBS: I pretend to use the HTML5 video player.

Thanks very much for your reply! =)

Answer (score 0):

As with all video questions, the answer is: It depends.

Some containers are designed for streaming (flv, mpeg-ts) and others are designed for random access (mp4, mkv). Some random access containers can be used for pseudo-streaming where the client can perform byte-range to performing random access over http.

If you have a user upload an flv, you can convert it as it streams up to you. If you have a user upload an mp4 with the moov atom at the end, you need to cache the entire file before you can do a conversion. if the moov atom is at the beginning, you can convert as it streams.